# Using horizontal fill to center doesn't work

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I want to use the symbol for logical disjunction (the 'V'), but I want this to be in the center of the two 'x = ..'.

Right now it's like this:
[image]

This is the code I'm using:

```
\paragraph{a)}
$
\begin{aligned}[t]
&D=b^2-4ac=5^2-4\cdot-2\cdot3=49 \\
&x=\dfrac{-5+\sqrt{49}}{2\cdot-2}=-\dfrac{1}{2}
&\hfill 
&\vee 
&\hfill
&x=\dfrac{-5-\sqrt{49}}{2\cdot-2}=3
\end{aligned}
$
```

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Inside the environments of the `amsmath` package, the command `\hfill` doesn't work like it does in "ordinary" material.

Comment: I think this would be better handled by a `gathered` environment rather than an `aligned`...

Comment: @Thruston The 'gathered' gives an error, I'm using documentclass{article} and I'm using the package 'amsmath'

Answer (score 2):

For simple lists of equations like this all you really need is an array with a single column that you can align left, center, or right.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\paragraph{a)}
$
\begin{array}[t]{l}
D=b^2-4ac=5^2-4\cdot-2\cdot3=49 \\
x=\dfrac{-5+\sqrt{49}}{2\cdot-2}=-\dfrac{1}{2}
\qquad\text{or}\qquad 
x=\dfrac{-5-\sqrt{49}}{2\cdot-2}=3
\end{array}
$
\end{document}
```

Use `\quad` or `\qquad` to make space in a line, where there's no need to line things up.

Comment: Your code is like this:http://i.imgur.com/3ZOJbdO.png

Comment: But I want to have this: http://i.imgur.com/43p70Wa.png

Comment: can't you do it with the 'aligned'?

Comment: @user3024879  No not really - `aligned` is for lining things up on a specific character, usually the = sign.  What  you want is a simple array, with a single left-aligned column.

Answer (score 2):

Here is version using `tabular` or `array` (saves you having to go into and out of math mode for each cell) :

[image]

### Notes:

- [The `showframe` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/showframe)
  was used just to show the page margins.
  It is not needed in your actual use case.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{showframe}

\newcommand*{\Length}{\dimexpr0.45\linewidth-1.0em\relax}% Adjustment for the paragraph label.

\begin{document}
\paragraph{a)}
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}p{\Length} @{}p{0.10\linewidth}<{\centering}@{} >{\hfill}p{\Length}@{}}
    $D=b^2-4ac=5^2-4\cdot-2\cdot3=49$ \\
    $x=\dfrac{-5+\sqrt{49}}{2\cdot-2}=-\dfrac{1}{2}$ & $\vee$  & $x=\dfrac{-5-\sqrt{49}}{2\cdot-2}=3$ \\
\end{tabular}
\paragraph{b)}
$\begin{array}[t]{@{}>{$}p{\Length}<{$} @{}>{\centering$}p{0.10\linewidth}<{$}@{} >{\hfill$}p{\Length}<{$}@{}}
    D=b^2-4ac=5^2-4\cdot-2\cdot3=49 \\
    x=\dfrac{-5+\sqrt{49}}{2\cdot-2}=-\dfrac{1}{2} & \vee  & x=\dfrac{-5-\sqrt{49}}{2\cdot-2}=3 \\
\end{array}$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,showframe}
\begin{document}
\paragraph{a)}
$
\begin{aligned}[t]
&D=b²-4ac=5²-4\cdot-2\cdot3=49 \\
&x=\dfrac{-5+√{49}}{2\cdot-2}=-\dfrac{1}{2}
&
\vee
\qquad\qquad\qquad
&
&x=\dfrac{-5-√{49}}{2\cdot-2}=3
\end{aligned}
$
\end{document}
```

[image]