# Graph doesn't stay within grid

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot

I've plotted two simple functions in Latex using tikz. It looks like this:
[image]

As you can see, the curve doesn't stay within its grid. How can I fix this?

This is my code. I'm using documentclass 'article':

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[step=1cm,color=gray!20] (-5,-5) grid (5,5);
  \draw[-] (-5,0) -- (5,0) node[right] {$x$};
  \draw (0,0) node[below left] {$O$};
  \draw[-] (0,-5) -- (0,5) node[above] {$y$};
  \foreach \x in {-5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
    \draw (\x cm,1pt) -- (\x cm,-1pt) node[anchor=north] {$\x$};
  \foreach \y in {-5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
    \draw (1pt,\y cm) -- (-1pt,\y cm) node[anchor=east] {$\y$};  
  \draw[scale=0.5,domain=-3:3,smooth,variable=\x,blue] plot ({\x},{\x^3});
  \draw[blue] (1,5) node[below right] {$y=x^3$};
  \draw[scale=0.5,domain=-3:3,smooth,variable=\y,red]  plot ({\y*\y},{\y});
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: It is much easier for others to help you if you post a complete MWE, not just a section of code.

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/213796/using-horizontal-fill-to-center-doesnt-work#comment501117_213796

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a proper rectangular clipping:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[step=1cm,color=gray!20] (-5,-5) grid (5,5);
  \draw[-] (-5,0) -- (5,0) node[right] {$x$};
  \draw (0,0) node[below left] {$O$};
  \draw[-] (0,-5) -- (0,5) node[above] {$y$};
  \foreach \x in {-5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
    \draw (\x cm,1pt) -- (\x cm,-1pt) node[anchor=north] {$\x$};
  \foreach \y in {-5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
    \draw (1pt,\y cm) -- (-1pt,\y cm) node[anchor=east] {$\y$};  
  \clip (-5,-5) rectangle (5,5);
  \draw[scale=0.5,domain=-3:3,smooth,variable=\x,blue] plot ({\x},{\x^3});
  \draw[blue] (1,5) node[below right] {$y=x^3$};
  \draw[scale=0.5,domain=-3:3,smooth,variable=\y,red]  plot ({\y*\y},{\y});
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

In this case, however, I'd suggest you to switch to [`pgfplots`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots) instead and use its built-in features to plot graphs; a simple example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  axis lines=middle,
  domain=-5:5,
  xtick={-5,-4,...,5},
  ytick={-5,-4,...,5},
  xmin=-5,
  xmax=5,
  ymin=-5,
  ymax=5,
  grid
  ]
  \addplot[blue,samples=100] {x^3};
  \addplot[red,domain=0:5,samples=100] {sqrt(x)};
  \addplot[red,domain=0:5,samples=100] {-sqrt(x)};
  \node[anchor=north west,blue] at (axis cs:2,5) {$y=x^{3}$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]